# IONIC - ANGULAR Why when click back button I have same multiple request?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, back-button

I have the back button on my pages.
When I stay on PAGE 1 and go to PAGE 2 I have only one request. And when I click the back button from PAGE 2 to PAGE 1 i receive a two same request. If I go to PAGE 2 again and go back I receive three same request.

Why ?

i have this on PAGE 1

```
ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('id_store')) {
        this.location.back();
        return;
      }
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.atv_id = paramMap.get('id_store');


        this.loadingCtrl
        .create({ keyboardClose: true, message: 'Carico categorie...' })
        .then(loadingEl => {
          loadingEl.present();

          this.subcriber = this.ristoserv.postRistoCategories(this.atv_id).subscribe( (response: any ) => {

            // check zona selezionata
            this.storage.getObject('zoneData').then((data: any) => {
            });

            this.categories = response;
            this.IdType = paramMap.get('id_type');

            this.isLoading = false;
            loadingEl.dismiss();

          }, errRes => {

            loadingEl.dismiss();
            const code = errRes.error.error.message;
            console.log('error', code);
            this.isLoading = true;

          });
        });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `ionViewWillEnter()` you create new route subscription.
You should unsubscribe from it.

Create property

```
private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
```

use it to unsubscribe

```
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe(paramMap => {
```

And emit it whenever component destroys.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
}
```

You can do this easier using a library [@ngneat/until-destroy](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy).

Or simply make sure you only initialize it once: if you only change parameter in your router it might not recreate your component - depending on [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation) config.

It would help if you showed how/when you call `ionViewWillEnter()`.

Comment: I call `ionViewWillEnter()` when open the page:

`export class RistoMenuPage implements OnInit {

  isLoading = false;
  categories: Category; // model
  atv_id = '';
  IdType = '';

  constructor( private ristoserv: RistoService, private location: Location, private router: Router,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private storage: StorageService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }`